# Setting up a CoreML Model in Swift - Image Classifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, machine-learning, coreml

I have trained a model to differentiate between malignant and benign skin lesions to potentially detect if a patient has skin cancer, and have converted my keras model to coreML. Now I am trying to apply my model to an ios app using swift (through Xcode) which I have no experience in at all (still learning through trial and error).

Currently I am trying to get the model working through a simple app that just takes an image from the phone's camera to get a predicted label as output, but I am quite stuck in getting the camera to actually work to do just that.

```
import UIKit
import CoreML
import Vision
import Social

@UIApplicationMain
class ViewControl: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var classificationResults : [VNClassificationObservation] = []

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    func detect(image: CIImage) {

        // Load the ML model through its generated class
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: weights_skin_cancer().model) else {
            fatalError("can't load ML model")
        }

        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, error in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation],
                let topResult = results.first
                else {
                    fatalError("unexpected result type from VNCoreMLRequest")
                }

                if topResult.identifier.contains("malignant") {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.navigationItem.title = "mal!"
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false


                    }
                }
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.navigationItem.title = "benign!"
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

                    }
                }


        }

        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

        do { try handler.perform([request]) }
        catch { print(error) }



    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {


        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

            imageView.image = image

            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


            guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
                fatalError("couldn't convert uiimage to CIImage")
            }

            detect(image: ciImage)

        }
    }


    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here's also the code used to convert my model to coreML for reference:

```
import coremltools

output_labels = ['benign', 'malignant']
scale = 1/255.
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('/Users/Grampun/Desktop/ISIC-Archive-Downloader-master/trained_models/lr_0.00006-400_DS-20_epochs/weights.best.from_scratch.6.hdf5',
                                                    input_names='image',
                                                    image_input_names='image',
                                                    output_names='output',
                                                    class_labels=output_labels,
                                                    image_scale=scale)

coreml_model.author = 'Jack Bugeja'
coreml_model.short_description = 'Model used to identify between benign and malignant skin lesions'

coreml_model.input_description['image'] = 'Dermascopic image of skin lesion to evaluate'
coreml_model.input_description['output'] = 'Malignant/Benign'

coreml_model.save(
    '/Users/Grampun/Desktop/ISIC-Archive-Downloader-master/trained_models/model_for_ios/lr_0.00006-400_DS-20_epochs/weights_skin_cancer.mlmodel')
```

Any help in general would be highly appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual question you're asking?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans sorry if wasn't clear, I was asking how I could get the camera working - what in my code is making my camera not activate once pressed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the camera:

   ```
   @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       let controller = UIImagePickerController()
       controller.sourceType = .camera
       controller.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
       controller.allowsEditing = false
       controller.delegate = self
       present(controller, animated: true)
   }
   ```
2. Add the `YourModel.mlmodel` to your project.
3. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` add this code:

   ```
   if let imageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
       if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.absoluteString) {
           self.getPrediction(image)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add this to get prediction:

   ```
   func getPrediction(_ image: UIImage) {
       let model = YourModel()

       guard let pixelBuffer = buffer(from: image) else { return }
       guard let prediction = try? model.prediction(image: pixelBuffer) else { return }

       print(prediction.classLabel) // Most likely image category as string value
   }
   ```
5. Use this helper function to make from your `UIImage` a `CVPixelBuffer` that you need to use it in `getPrediction()`

   ```
   func buffer(from image: UIImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
       let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
       var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
       let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
       guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
           return nil
       }

       CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
       let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

       let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
       let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

       context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
       context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

       UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
       image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
       UIGraphicsPopContext()
       CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

       return pixelBuffer
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately I am unable to open the camera as of this point.

Comment: @Grampun I edited my answer, see if that solve your problem

Comment: You may also need to add permissions to your app's Info.plist, otherwise it will not be able to access the camera. There should be an error message about this in Xcode's debug output pane.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans you're right. Needs to add `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` to Info.plist

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans added the permissions to .plist however the camera is still not functioning. will try to work on it more to hopefully get it working...

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I only can assume that you're trying on the simulator. Try on a real device.